# Voting system - onclick, active class, removing it as well

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

So, I want to let users vote by pressing an up or a down arrow. Not too difficult, one should say. It's not hard to create the Ajax calls, but for now I'm stuck at the visual stuff.

My HTML:

```
<td class="td5">
  <a class="vote" href="#up"><em class="vote-icon up"></em></a>
  <a class="vote" href="#down"><em class="vote-icon down"></em></a>
</td>
```

CSS:

```
.vote.active { border-color: #ff8000; }
.vote-icon { background: url('votes.png') no-repeat; display: inline-block; width: 10px; height: 8px; }
.vote-icon.up { background-position: 0 0; }
 .vote-icon.up.active, .vote:hover .vote-icon.up { background-position: 0 -24px; }
.vote-icon.down { background-position: -20px 0; }
 .vote-icon.down.active, .vote:hover .vote-icon.down { background-position: -20px -24px; }
```

My jQuery:

```
$(function() {
  $('.vote').click(function() {
    $(this).siblings('.vote-icon').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
    $('> .vote-icon', this).addClass('active');
 });
});
```

It makes it active, but doesn't remove the active class if the other one is clicked. Nor does it remove it (and the vote) when you click an already active vote. Any help?

SOLVED!

Settled with:

```
    $(this).siblings('.vote-icon').toggleClass('active');
    $(this).siblings().find('.vote-icon').removeClass('active');
    $('> .vote-icon', this).toggleClass('active');
```

Comment: Seems like a perfect use for `toggleClass`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change

```
$(this).siblings('.vote-icon').removeClass('active');
```

to

```
$(this).siblings().find('.vote-icon').removeClass('active');
```

[**Working demo here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/S864e/)

Answer (score 2):

Just replace

```
$(this).siblings('.vote-icon').removeClass('active');
```

By

```
$('.vote-icon').removeClass('active');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `toggleClass`

```
$(this).siblings('.vote-icon').toggleClass('active');
$(this).toggleClass('active');
$('> .vote-icon', this).toggleClass('active');
```

Comment: Doesn't remove the other vote. It toggles them alright, but when pressing up first, then down, both are selected.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {
  $('.vote').click(function() {
    $('.active').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
    $('> .vote-icon', this).addClass('active');
 });
});
```

Comment: Works fine -- for just one row. If you have multiple rows all with their own vote, not going to work.